# Getting started on iOS - for Android developers?

Tags: android, ios

Is there any good resource for getting started with iOS development if you're an Android developer?
I remember Microsoft had courses for Android developers to make them jump over to WP.
I'm looking for a similar thing (preferably in an online form) for iOS.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://www.RayWenderlich.com has a wealth of iOS tutorials for beginners, experts, and programmers looking to pick up a new language.

This one in particular is written for someone who knows how to program but wants to learn Objective-C. https://www.raywenderlich.com/21320/objectively-speaking-a-crash-course-in-objective-c-ios6

Good Luck :) Welcome to the community.

Comment: Thanks, that 2nd link looks very interesting.
I was hoping for something targeted to Android devs, but this seems to be the closest to what I need.

Comment: BTW this doesn't mean I'm leaving Android, it just means I don't see any value in being narrow minded and hating something because you also like something else ;)

Comment: LoL well I enjoy being narrow minded and hating Android. Except for 9Patch ;p those are pretty cool.

Comment: I'm sure I could tell you about some more stuff you'd like, but that's not the point here ;) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Any of the apple developer tutorials are good for anyone jumping into iOS.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Guides

Answer (score 1):

Standford's course is also very good. I'm following it right now and I highly recommend it.

https://itunes.apple.com/es/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

More info here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p